# Sharepoint survey: How to identify the question fields when fetching survey information from the Lists web service?

Tags: sharepoint, web-services, survey

I am wanting to access survey information via the Lists **web service** and display the questions contained in the survey.

The result contains a large number of **Field** nodes some of which are the questions in the survey. The other fields contain other information such as author, last changed etc.

How can I pick out the questions? I had thought that all non-questions would be hidden but this is not the case.

Here is my code as it is at the moment. It returns about 16 items. The survey has 6 questions...

```
// read question definitions
string[] HandleTypes = new string[] { "Number", "DateTime", "Text", "Choice", "GridChoice", "Boolean" };
var query = from n in node.Descendants(ns+"Field")
            where (n.Attribute("Hidden") == null || n.Attribute("Hidden").Value.ToLower() == "true")
            && (n.Attribute("Type") != null && HandleTypes.Contains(n.Attribute("Type").Value))
            select new Question(n.Attribute("ID").Value)
            {
                Text = n.Attribute("DisplayName").Value,
                QuestionType = n.Attribute("Type").Value,
                Element = n
            };
```

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute "SourceID" for question fields is a GUID. 
All other fields have a SourceID with "http://schema..."

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. I can add (deploy via schema.xml) a field with `sourceId="http://schema...";` and it will still show as a survey question

Comment: if you deploy a custom scheme then it is in your hands to pick out the questions from the survey. For using the standard/out of the box survey my approach is working although i have the admit that the solution is more a less an assumption at the same time,

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest workaround is to find out the `InternalName`s of the built-in fields, put them in an array, and then to check if the fieldname is in that array or not. For instance, you will most likely have "Title", "Created", "Author" et cetera. This page will give you some hints, which of the fields are built-in: http://www.johnholliday.net/downloads/fieldswss.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SPField.Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.group.aspx) to find out if a field is a 'Base' column such as ID/Author etc or a custom column which will be a question or page separator.

The page separator is a particular [field type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.type.aspx) so you should be able to get those by

```
if (SPField.Type == SPFieldTypes.PageSeperator)
```

Comment: Opps - me bad. Didn't read the Q properly! You should be able to use the GetList web service to get the schema of the list and the types of its fields.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it treats all new columns (not ones from the parent content types) as questions. 
One way to retrieve only questions is to grab all the fields that are in "Overview" view (except for Author column); another way would be to grab all the fields that are not coming from a parent content type, i.e. new fields.